# Print at jTextArea using .setText returns error non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, file-io

I am trying to print the content of the file into a jTextArea but i got this error:

> error non-static variable cannot be referenced from static context

This is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package compiler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form gui
     */
    public gui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPopupMenu1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        editArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea3 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu3 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu4 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenu5 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        editArea.setColumns(20);
        editArea.setRows(5);
        editArea.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                editAreaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(editArea);

        jLabel1.setText("Edit area");

        jTextArea2.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jLabel2.setText("Label");

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Input");

        jTextArea3.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea3.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea3.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jTextArea3);

        jLabel4.setText("Output");

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setText("Open");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("Save");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Execute");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        jMenu3.setText("Next");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu3);

        jMenu4.setText("Assemble");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu4);

        jMenu5.setText("About");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu5);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(231, 231, 231)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 246, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addGap(25, 25, 25))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                          

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void editAreaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        try {

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
            // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            // Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String a[] = strLine.split(" ");
                 editArea.setText("Call Load");
                switch(a[0]) {
                    case "LOAD":
                       // jTextArea1.setText("Call Load");
                        //System.out.println();
                        break;
                    case "STORE":
                        System.out.println("Call Halt");
                        break;
                    case "ADD":
                        System.out.println("Call Add");
                        break;
                    case "SUBT":
                        System.out.println("Call Subt");
                        break;
                    case "JUMP":
                        System.out.println("Call Jump");
                        break;
                    case "MULT":
                        System.out.println("Call Mult");
                        break;
                    case "ENTER":
                        System.out.println("Call Enter");
                        break;
                    case "DISP":
                        System.out.println("Call Disp");
                        break;  
                    case "END":
                        System.out.println("Call End");
                        break; 
                    case "CHKR":
                        System.out.println("Call Chkr");
                        break;    
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new gui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea editArea;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu jPopupMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Is this try-block inside your main method?

Comment: @Izmaki yes it's inside public static void main(String args[])

Comment: You don't want all your code inside the main method. In theory, all you need is the following line of code: `new MyClass();`, given that your class is called `MyClass` and you use the default constructor. Inside the constructor, make sure that you do the appropriate set up (the "construction") of your class, and call appropriate methods to handle the logic of your program.

Comment: @Izmaki would you mind showing an example?

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you declare your `editArea` variable as a non static, and if it's true, we founde the fail. You can not invoque an instance variable on a static context.

Comment: @ColdHack how do you not declare it as non static? this is using netbeans

Comment: One option is, instead of try do it on main method, you can put this after `initComponents()`. I'm assuming that you are using the GUI editor of NetBean.

Comment: The `initComponents` method, normally stays on contructor of your class.

Comment: @magicianIam: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/Jpq40bfd It's almost the same as what ColdHack suggested, however you **only** want to have actual construction inside your constructor. All logic should go elsewhere.

Comment: @magicianIam: You're still trying to call a non-static variable from a static context. You need to copy everything inside your `public static void main(String args[])` method below the comment that says `//</editor-fold>` - that is, your old code snippet - and place it inside a new method. You could call this method `readFromFile`, for example `public void readFromFile()`. When you've done so, add this line `readFromFile();` inside your constructor (`public gui()`) right bellow the line `initComponents();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
package compiler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form gui
 */
public gui() {
    initComponents();
    methodToReadFile();
}

...

private void methodToReadFile()
{
    try {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
        // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;
        // Read File Line By Line
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String a[] = strLine.split(" ");
             editArea.setText("Call Load");
            switch(a[0]) {
                case "LOAD":
                   // jTextArea1.setText("Call Load");
                    //System.out.println();
                    break;
                case "STORE":
                    System.out.println("Call Halt");
                    break;
                case "ADD":
                    System.out.println("Call Add");
                    break;
                case "SUBT":
                    System.out.println("Call Subt");
                    break;
                case "JUMP":
                    System.out.println("Call Jump");
                    break;
                case "MULT":
                    System.out.println("Call Mult");
                    break;
                case "ENTER":
                    System.out.println("Call Enter");
                    break;
                case "DISP":
                    System.out.println("Call Disp");
                    break;  
                case "END":
                    System.out.println("Call End");
                    break; 
                case "CHKR":
                    System.out.println("Call Chkr");
                    break;    
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

...

//the main
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Att: You class must start with a capital letter (Gui).

Comment: thanks for this but how do I print it per new line? thank you